# CSS templates for standard html elements?

Tags: css, template

I'm not looking for html page templates... but rather basic element templates. Is anyone aware of a site that carries this type of template?

I want to create my own layouts and such, but I would love to have some simple copy/paste templates that style:

- Forms
- Buttons
- Tables
- Typography
- Some general classes (alerts, info, etc, images)

Comment: probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32875/browsers-default-css;
for forms, http://formalize.me/ is a good hint;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Blueprint framework](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) is broken into a few modules; go to "Live Demos." The text module has a nice size scale to it but is otherwise pretty boring. The form module is simple but attractive, and has some nice alert/info/etc styles.

[Formy](http://code.google.com/p/formy-css-framework/) is dedicated to form layout, giving you easy tools for doing things like annoying horizontal forms and aligned labels. But it's otherwise pretty unstyled, so colors and such are up to you.

[Typogridphy](http://csswizardry.com/typogridphy/) is, as you might've guess, focused on typography and includes a couple tricks many others don't usually. [Baseline](http://baselinecss.com/) also has a focus on typographic measure, but is a bit more complete, closer to Blueprint.

For buttons, have a look at [CSSButtons](http://www.cssbuttons.net/), or [Sexy Buttons](http://code.google.com/p/sexybuttons/)(which links to a few other projects at bottom). Both are frameworks that can be expanded upon stylistically, though include some example implementations as well.